# NSLocalizedString always returns capitalized text

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

Ive run into an issue where NSLocalizedString is always returning strings capitalized regardless of its input.  localization was working
and Im assuming I did something that caused this but I cannot seem
to figure out exactly what changed.

Here's my code:

```
func localize(_ str: String) -> String {
    print("str in: \(str)")
    return NSLocalizedString(str, comment: "")
}
```

I call it like this:

```
let txt = self.localize("Question")
print("txt = \(txt)")
```

Output:

```
str in: Question
txt = QUESTION
```

Things Ive tried:

1. Ive grep'd all of my .strings files and confirmed there is no
       'QUESTION' in there.
2. Removed app from Simulator and re-run app
3. Changed incoming string to something that doesn't exist in any file such as 'randomxxyxxy'

Ive tried searching for quite a while on this issue and wasn't able to find anything that was like this problem.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: FYI - your use of your `localize` method to wrap `NSLocalizedString` is not a good idea. You want calls to `NSLocalizedString` all throughout your code. Each should be written for a specific string and comment. Then you can use `genstrings` to generate your base localized strings file.

Comment: Just to make sure: Is *that* localize function called or might there be another candidate?

Comment: Thanks for the genstrings advice, thats good to know going forward.  I changed the 'localize' method to something else that im sure is being called within the same file, no difference.

Comment: Before return add one line like this, func localize(_ str: String) -> String {
    print("str in: \(str)")
    print (NSLocalizedString(str, comment: ""))
    return NSLocalizedString(str, comment: "")
} If it's right, you must call the wrong function.

Comment: Still shows all caps there as well

Comment: NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:) use the full function and setting value.

Comment: same results, still returns all caps

Answer (score 17):

When your app is trying to localize a string but cannot find the translated text for it then it will show it in capitals. This is done to show you that the capitalized text is not localized. You can disable the capitalization of those cases by disabling the option: Show not-localized strings

This is how you do that:

> 1. Edit the scheme
> 2. Select the “Run” action and click the “Options” tab
> 3. Uncheck the “Show non-localized strings” option

[image]

In your case I think that your strings' localization is not working and so they are capitalized because that setting is activated.